# ARP scan network with IPv6 scapy

Tags: python, networking, ipv6, scapy, packets

I recently wanted to get into IPv6 networking, and I was wondering if it is possible to do an ARP scan of a network with IPV6 in python + scapy?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: IPv6 doesn't use ARP. The equivalent is neighbour discovery, which is implemented with ICMPv6. However, the address space is so big that it's not practically possible to scan all of it.

Comment: If you could scan a million addresses per second, it would take over half a million years to scan all the addresses on a standard `/64` IPv6 subnet.